# I have a lot of loop devices, what are they and should I get rid of them?

Tags: 16.04, filesystem, loop-device

Whenever I open my file browser, there are a these loop devices, I don't know what they are, I tried to look up but I didn't understand what they are. They keep increasing every so often, I haven't seen the frequency of this but I know there weren't as many loop device directories before. 
My question is, should I get rid of them? Should I just let them be?

Thanks for the help.

[image]

Comment: Using snap for package management will leave loop devices around.