# Linux os boot up extremely slow and strange loops are becoming more and more, how to speed up!

Tags: boot

I just installed ubuntu 18.04, it is booting very slowly. Help needed!!! I ran a blame command to see which one runs most of time, and I know I didn't figure out how to set up printer on my laptop. I know there are some ACPI errors shown when shutting down my machine.

BTW, there are so many loops, I am confused by these loops and wanted to remove them, but they grow from 4 to 15...in a week. Igore if you feel it's too easy, and don't thumbs down for me, cause it has been an headache for me for weeks...I don't want to give up...

```
$ systemd-analyze blame
         15.524s configure-printer@usb-003-002.service
         13.523s dev-sda6.device
         13.470s dev-sda7.device
         10.584s dev-loop13.device
         10.384s dev-loop0.device
         10.345s dev-loop1.device
         10.321s dev-loop7.device
         10.295s dev-loop6.device
         10.294s dev-loop2.device
         10.158s dev-loop4.device
         10.122s dev-loop5.device
         10.104s dev-loop8.device
         10.072s dev-loop3.device
         10.031s dev-loop9.device
         10.007s dev-loop10.device
          9.983s dev-loop11.device
          9.929s dev-loop12.device
          9.873s systemd-journal-flush.service
          7.283s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          6.872s dev-loop14.device
          5.899s plymouth-start.service
          5.880s dev-loop15.device
          5.715s plymouth-quit-wait.service
          5.487s systemd-udevd.service
          5.321s systemd-sysctl.service
          5.170s udisks2.service
          5.088s snap-skype-38.mount
          5.037s snap-skype-41.mount
          4.785s grub-common.service
          4.583s ModemManager.service
          4.029s snapd.service
          3.955s networking.service
          3.274s systemd-rfkill.service
          2.998s apport.service
          2.628s speech-dispatcher.service
          2.622s bluetooth.service
          2.620s avahi-daemon.service
          2.612s gpu-manager.service
          2.609s alsa-restore.service
          2.597s networkd-dispatcher.service
          2.592s rsyslog.service
```

Comment: Possibly related [I have a lot of loop devices, what are they and should I get rid of them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013910/i-have-a-lot-of-loop-devices-what-are-they-and-should-i-get-rid-of-them)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the dev-loop services that started on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056645/what-are-the-dev-loop-services-that-started-on-boot)